# Complete LoginTest does not run in android using espresso

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am using espresso and ui automation for test cases and generating report by running gradlew.bat :app:createDebugCoverageReport in command prompt.

**My Problem:-**

I am having LoginTest activity which contains 4 or 5 methods in it.Methods are named in sorting order using **@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)**.When i run the command **gradlew.bat :app:createDebugCoverageReport** in command prompt it runs one method only,after completion stop the app.For example :- **It runs aa_doLogin() only.Does not run cc_secondmethod and bb_firstmethod.**

**My Code:-**

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class LoginTest{
@Before
setup(){
}

@Test 
aa_doLogin(){
   bb_firstmethod()
}
@Test
bb_firstmethod(){
  cc_secondmethod
}
@Test
cc_secondmethod(){
}
}
```

Error :-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:189)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.findRoot(RootViewPicker.java:134)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:69)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:23)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:68)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:120)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Shivram: is this a unit test or an espresso test? without @ RunWith or @ Rule components, it looks like the code posted is lacking basic Espresso requirements. See this answer for an example of what to add: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38200643/3195307

Comment: I have used @Rule but not RuleWith,but by using RuleWith the report does not generate properly Paul

Comment: @Shivram can you confirm if this is intended to be a unit test or a UI (Espresso) test?

Comment: Espresso testing.Can u tell me why this error is coming?

Comment: I believe that this is because you don't have an ActivityTestRule with @Rule defined. This is why I referred you to the example link above. Without a complete code example, we can't know for sure.

Comment: @PaulBruce I have already tried this,but by using this my project runs like it is getting refresh.And also I have fragment in my app.So how to call ActivityTestRule for fragment.